# Conditionally prohibit function parameter depending on enum value

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I have a function `fn` with two possible call signatures:

```js
enum Mode {
  NEEDS_ARG,
  ANYTHING_ELSE
}

fn(Mode.NEEDS_ARG, arg)  // Call signature 1
fn(Mode.ANYTHING_ELSE)   // Call signature 2

fn(Mode.ANYTHING_ELSE, arg)   // Invalid
```

Depending on the value of the first argument, I'd like to prohibit the second argument.

Here's my attempt at typing such a function:

```js
enum Mode {
  NEEDS_ARG,
  ANYTHING_ELSE
}

type Arg = "argument"

function fn(
  mode: Mode,
  arg: typeof mode extends Mode.NEEDS_ARG ? Arg : never
) {
  arg  // TS infers this as 'never'
}
```

From the [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) on Conditional Types:

> When the type on the left of the extends is assignable to the one on the right, then you’ll get the type in the first branch (the “true” branch); otherwise you’ll get the type in the latter branch (the “false” branch).

I see why my implementation doesn't work - `typeof mode` evaluates to `Mode`, which is not assignable to `Mode.NEEDS_ARG`.

But what is the right way to type this function?

---

### EDIT

I run into a couple of issues trying to adapt the generic argument approach provided by @jcalz

#### Issue 1: `arg` type doesn't get narrowed based on the value of `mode`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsg9gE2FA3gWAFBSgOQKJ4AiAygPoCCASgOIA0m2OA8hTZgL6aYAuAngA7JyAJwDmUALxQARAEMxkUN2kBuTAGM4IAM7co88VLkKIS1VwwAzMCHXcAllqiWQAHgAqUYAA9uoBNqwiMAAfAAUDFAQwQBcUO70WFAAdKnCwLpxnj5+IAFBSMn4RGRU1FAA-FAA2gZxIqIAulBx1Y2YAJSokZo6erVizVLpupH2lmEGUACEElI2SJb2IMAIXehJ2FNQAPQ78QLI9oEg8sJwAO6rkZxJ42HRSJJzBcBFBCSs1OuRW2LYewOgm06mE9n4el09gANtCoNwABbLADWgURxygGLgEMcp2hNw4FhcYXghWKnzKtH0Yg6KgB+wAwrJYVBtPZRKduGB0lAAIyYYmkt7ML607DiiW7RnMuFsjmyLk8gBMmCAA)

I expected the type of `arg` to be narrowed when `mode === Mode.NEEDS_ARG`, but it isn't

```js
function fn<T extends Mode>(
  mode: T,
  ...rest: T extends Mode.NEEDS_ARG ? [arg: Arg] : []
) {
  const [arg] = rest
  if(arg !== undefined) {
    arg  // Type is narrowed to 'Arg'
  }
  if(mode === Mode.NEEDS_ARG) {
    arg  // Typescript still thinks this is 'Arg | undefined'
  }
}
```

#### Issue 2: Doesn't work without the spread syntax

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsg9gE2FA3gWAFBSgOQKJ4AiAygPoCCASgOIA0m2OA8hTZgL6aYAuAngA7JyAJwDmUALxQARAEMxkUN2kBuTAGM4IAM7co88VLkKIS1VwwAzMCHXcAllqiWQAHgAqUYAA9uoBNqwiMAAfAAUDFAQwQBcUO70WPpicZ4+fiABQUgAdPhEZFTUUAD8UCKicTZIlvYgwAiYAJSonBiYLmHwufkkrHTJok0q2AD0o1AAwrIANjNQ2vaiILLcYMLIAIwdIF3BeSxFw9gnp1DjU7Pzi8ur68gATJhAA)

If I replace the `...rest` param with a single `arg` param, Typescript complains

```js
function fn<T extends Mode>(
  mode: T,
  arg: T extends Mode.NEEDS_ARG ? Arg: never
) {}

fn(Mode.NEEDS_ARG, arg);  // Ok
fn(Mode.NO_ARG);          // Err: 'An argument for 'arg' was not provided.'
```

Comment: You want it to be *optional* if `Mode.NO_ARG` is passed? Or do you want it to be *prohibited*? ... and what is the intended return type of `fn()`, is it void?  And do you care about the implementation, or just the call signature(s)?

Comment: Assuming you want `Mode.NO_ARG` to prohibit the second argument, you can use [any of these approaches](https://tsplay.dev/w6XMrm), depending on your use case. If you want me to write any or all of those up as an answer, let me know.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the detailed playground sketch! I ended up using the `GenericConditional` approach.
For my use case `arg` being optional or prohibited are equivalent, but it's good to know we have options there too :)

Comment: "For my use case `arg` being optional or prohibited are equivalent"... I don't quite understand this, but could you [edit] the question to make it clear whether one should or should not allow `fn(Mode.NO_ARG, arg)` to be called?  Even if you don't care, it would be helpful for the question to be less ambiguous and I can tailor my answer to whichever version you go with.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to `arg` being prohibited when `mode != Mode.NEEDS_ARG`

Comment: I've run into a couple of issues while trying to implement the generic function approach - I've added these on to the question.
Any chance you could explain these issues in an answer?

Comment: These issues are unfortunately scope creep at this point, since they are based on an answer I haven't even written yet. Issue #1; if you care about narrowing inside the implementation I would avoid generic functions with conditional types, and had I known that I'd probably have just suggested the rest-union answer.  Issue #2 reads like "if I replace my eyeglasses with drinking glasses, I can no longer see." I can say "those aren't equivalent and you shouldn't do that" but an explanation for why they aren't equivalent seems like a long digression since that approach does not work.

Comment: I answered as thoroughly as I could; hopefully that helps you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to allow these calls:

```
fn(Mode.NEEDS_ARG, arg); // okay
fn(Mode.ANYTHING_ELSE); // okay
```

While disallowing these:

```
fn(Mode.NEEDS_ARG); // error!
fn(Mode.ANYTHING_ELSE, arg); // error!
```

There are several ways to accomplish this in TypeScript.

---

The traditional solution is to make `fn()` an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with two call signatures:

```
// call signatures
function fn(mode: Mode.NEEDS_ARG, arg: Arg): void;
function fn(mode: Mode.ANYTHING_ELSE): void;
// impl
function fn(mode: Mode, arg?: Arg) {

}
```

Nowadays if you have overloads that have the same return type, you can refactor overloads into a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions):

```
function fn(
  ...args: [mode: Mode.NEEDS_ARG, arg: Arg] | [mode: Mode.ANYTHING_ELSE]
): void {

}
```

Alternatively you could make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to allow/disallow a second argument based on the specific type of the first argument:

```
function fn<T extends Mode>(
  mode: T,
  ...rest: T extends Mode.NEEDS_ARG ? [arg: Arg] : []
): void {

}
```

Because the number of function parameters changes depending on `T`, you can't rewrite this as a single call signature *without* a rest parameter.  There was some work done to let you mark a parameter as type `void` and it would be optional, but it doesn't work with generics (see [microsoft/TypeScript#29131](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29131)), so it's just not possible. You need a rest parameter to write the call signature this way.

---

All of those should work to some degree from the *caller's* side.  This is more or less the end of the answer to the question as originally asked.

---

---

In the *implementation*, though, there are limitations.  If you really want to treat the arguments as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and narrow based on whether `mode` is `Mode.NEEDS_ARG` or not, and you want type safety from the compiler, you pretty much need to use the union-of-tuples technique:

```
function fn(
  ...args: [mode: Mode.NEEDS_ARG, arg: Arg] | [mode: Mode.ANYTHING_ELSE]
): void {
  const mode = args[0];
  if (mode === Mode.NEEDS_ARG) {
    const arg = args[1];
    arg.toUpperCase(); // okay
  } else {
    args.length // known to be 1
  }
}
```

Inside the function we get a variable named `mode` from `args`, such that when we check `mode` it acts as a discriminant for `args` (this support was [added in TS4.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants); before this you would need to say `args[0]` everywhere instead of `mode`).

It's not *beautiful* but it works.

---

If you do try this with the overloads, your implementation will be too loosely typed and it will fail to realize that checking `mode` has any implication for the type of `arg`

```
// call signatures
function fn(mode: Mode.NEEDS_ARG, arg: Arg): void;
function fn(mode: Mode.ANYTHING_ELSE): void;
// impl
function fn(mode: Mode, arg?: Arg) {
  if (mode === Mode.NEEDS_ARG) {
    arg.toUpperCase(); // error
  }
}
```

You can of course use a type assertion like `arg!.toUpperCase()`, but this is not very type safe.  Overload implementations are sort of "cut off" from the call signatures, and do not "prune" the call signature set based on control flow.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#22609](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22609) for a relevant feature request to support this.

---

On the other hand, if you try to do this with the generic conditional, you have a similar problem; in this case it's because the compiler does not know what `T` is inside the body, and thus does not know how to evaluate `T extends Mode.NEEDS_ARG ? [arg: Arg] : []`:

```
function fn<T extends Mode>(
  mode: T,
  ...rest: T extends Mode.NEEDS_ARG ? [arg: Arg] : []
): void {
  rest // T extends Mode.NEEDS_ARG ? [arg: "argument"] : []
  if (mode === Mode.NEEDS_ARG) {
    rest[1].toUpperCase(); // error
  }
}
```

Again, you can use type assertions or other ways of suppressing the error, but currently the body of generic functions does not know how to do much with conditional types.  You just can't narrow the type of a generic type parameter by checking its value.  See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808 for a feature request that could help with this.

---

So there you go.  You have several options for giving types to the call signature(s) for the function.  If you need to have type safety inside the implementation, the closest you can get is to use the union-of-rest-tuple approach.  Otherwise you will have to forgo some type safety.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJITACuYSAsgPYAmyBhppAcgKKcAiAygH0AggCUA4gBoSbIewCaAFQASASXZiBnADJ9O0gL5FpAFwCeMZEIBOAcyQBeJACIQtquWNOA3NPh1gUMZIrnaOLm6QwJ4+xKxIoJCwCMgA8gBuEFYYdCAMUHhGcaQA9MVI6BgYSFAAljagxhRW0NKkAGYUwPDGNf5IbcAAFGCMEABctKMAdFy8gqKSwbYT1jYAlBNpdDUMMWz9nd29wP1DI0wT9ExTsoqq6po6nBtIWzt7bKVINWAwGK0HLo9PoDYajS6jCRLGwAfhWtjWBSKbBqbSQYKYDnsjiuEBm3H4wnEiJY+32ISmxjoAFUYBYrABhEBQCCDNZeJBfTJWOhWAGkQzIwUA0G4-FzImLELszllOgAaxAphFQzFt2Uag02l0Mq+CqVKsGYtmhIWurK3N5AEJDWr5BqHtrOFDpRyuVYeVYbbEBYVSAloHBEEhqcBjik2iJoMYFBQ-tAkSLDsCTqD+UgppmQlAJgBtc7jSbXE3zcQu5ZIVYAXSQAB8kPnwUW8er7lqnlWAS83gwkWTyv5AkgCw5oVBcwAGKsffao9Ej7E46YlyUk9OkPwBIIhUfZ3MARmn6+hlJpdMyTJZbLdcsVyuRArIGBZff7Y6mGHINmMAAtZUh5WAOgAHcTipJAACNkH3dNBX2OC2FFZcCVLKUERvJB9XvfYkOuVtNUeHUMKw21kIlM0MMtL1SLw+020I51oXNMgPWtAw-XicBA2SJAxHITIangBl-AYGoU0wRNkQ6IFjlOAAeBQyAAD2Mcg8mbAA+QZ0wLCYFCkB8M0zZpAj05TVOAdTjRQyUkBhBsQnhGwazzTtkW7bZe1JMkTKCL5FIgFS1PyazyPEOyHIrcIbHcKInBchs3P7OcMWQRdm3FU1iVfftfIPKtT1pelL1ZZiqNggFhSk1UyKytD1mIu8aJbOiCKdZiSOqo1atQsrWOorq7TuNqnnLBr-yo712NifQgA)